# JQGrid with two vertical scrollbars (left and right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Using JQGrid 4.5.4

I have a requirement to have both vertical scrollbar on my JQGrid on both the left and right.

Sample mockup:
[image: Sample Dual Vertical Scrollbar]

Is this possible? I have searched extensively and found an example of two horizontal scrollbars, but I was unable to find an example of two vertical scrollbars on both left and right sides of the JQGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications based on hect0r90's answer. This function is called whenever the grid is initialized, in case content changes. There WILL be a problem with this solution if a horizontal scrollbar is present. I did not fix it because this is not an issue for me.

```
function FormatLeftVerticalScrollbar() {
    var leftScrollID = 'leftScroll';
    var leftScrollContainerID = 'leftScrollContainer';

    //Get the body and header
    var jqgridBody = $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv");
    var jqgridHeader = $(".ui-state-default.ui-jqgrid-hdiv");

    //See if the scrollbar and container already exist
    var leftScroll = $("#" + leftScrollID);
    var leftScrollContainer = $("#" + leftScrollContainerID);

    //Add a new div with another div inside for the left scrollbar
    if(leftScroll == null ||
        leftScroll.length == 0)
    {
        jqgridHeader.after(
        '<div id="' + leftScrollID + '" style="z-index:1000; position:absolute; height:' + jqgridBody.height() + 'px; overflow:scroll; width:17px;">' +
            '<div id="' + leftScrollContainerID + '" style=" width:30px;"></div>' +
        '</div>');
        leftScroll = $("#" + leftScrollID);
        leftScrollContainer = $("#" + leftScrollContainerID);
    }

    //Set scroll content height to the height of the content
    var contentHeight = jqgridBody[0].scrollHeight;
    $("#" + leftScrollContainerID).height(contentHeight);

    //Syncronize both scrollbars
    jqgridBody.scroll(function () {
        $("#" + leftScrollID).scrollTop(jqgridBody.scrollTop());
    });
    $("#" + leftScrollID).scroll(function () {
        jqgridBody.scrollTop($("#" + leftScrollID).scrollTop());
    });
}
```

This is the best I could come up with until Oleg shows up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a small function added on loadComplete event.

This function creates a new div for the left scrollbar and then it sycronices both scrollbars.

```
                    loadComplete: function(){
                        var jqgridHeader = $(".ui-state-default.ui-jqgrid-hdiv");
                        // Add a new div with another div inside for the left scrollbar
                        jqgridHeader.after(
                            '<div id="leftScroll" style="z-index:1000; position:absolute; height:150px; overflow:scroll; width:17px;">'+
                                '<div id="leftScrollContent" style=" width:17px;"></div>' +
                            '</div>'
                        );
                        // Set to the new new div the sice of the jqgrid body
                        $("#leftScrollContent").css("height",($("#sortrows").height()));

                        var jqgridBody = $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv");
                        // Syncronice both scrollbars
                        jqgridBody.scroll(function () { 
                            $("#leftScroll").scrollTop(jqgridBody.scrollTop());
                        });
                        $("#leftScroll").scroll(function () { 
                            jqgridBody.scrollTop($("#leftScroll").scrollTop());
                        });
                    }
```

***The left scrollbar overlaps the first grid column**

Comment: This does not work for me, the scrollbar does not span the height of the grid. I think there are two issues:
First is that the "leftScroll" div should have its height set to the that of the grid (I've fixed this in your example).
Second is that "leftScrollContent" is not being set properly. I am not sure where the "sortrows" div is coming from, but I do not seem to have one.